# IIS URL rewrite from another root server to directory

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have an npm server to dev some apps with ArcGIS Experience Builder ( https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/ ).

I want to deploy it on a web server to share the environment with colleagues.

In this server I have IIS  and I want to use it as a reverse proxy to access to this.

When we launch npm server and client, it is accessible on https::/localhost:3001/ but all on root folder.

- Access page is on : https://localhost:3001/page/set-portalurl,
- summary is on https://localhost:3001/
- dev is on https://localhost:3001/builder?...

I try to add this rule:

```
 <rule name="ArcGIS Experience" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^ArcgisExperience(\/?|(\/+.*))$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:3001{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
 </rule>
```

or

```
 <rule name="ArcGIS Experience" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^ArcgisExperience(\/?|(\/+.*))$" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="https://localhost:3001/{R:1}" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
 </rule>
```

But when I go to https://example.com/ArcgisExperience I'm automatically redirected to https://example.com/page/set-portalurl, which is the access page on npm server... I would like https://example.com/ArcgisExperience/page/set-portalurl

How can I do this?

Comment: You can refer to the official website to do: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: I try but i think it modify my url and forget the folder.

Comment: Just include your file path in the rewrite rule to reach the web page correctly, or you want to achieve other situations.